# Is there a way to add user defined data to a viewmodel at design time?

Tags: mdriven

What is the best  way to add user defined data to a ViewModel at design time?

At runtime I want to display a subset of ViewModels for a class that don't require a root element. To do this at the moment I am tagging the ViewModels at design time by creating a ViewModel variable and assign it an intialvalue and using it as follows:

```
   ViewModelUserControl vmc = new ViewModelUserControl();
   vmc.ViewModelName = name;
   vmc.SetEcoSpace(ecoSpace);
   string vmTitle = vmc.ViewModel.ViewModelVariables
               .Find(x =>x.Name=="vmUserTitle")?.InitialValue ?? "";
   if (vmTitle != "")
   {
        ...display and do stuff with the ViewModel...
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

ViewModels can have TaggedValues, on all levels. I would use that instead of a variable defintion.

Comment: string TaggedValue = vmc.ViewModel.TaggedValues.ValueForTag("DoDisplay","False");